# How do I create a case insensitive automatic OrientDB index?

Tags: indexing, case-insensitive, orientdb

I understand that it's supposed to be possible to create a case insensitive automatic [OrientDB index](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Indexes) through the *Collate=CI* option, but so far I've been unsuccessful in my attempts at making it work. Nor have I been able to dig up documentation on this feature. I've tried the following index creation command (in the OrientDB console), which works except for the `Collate=CI` bit:

```
create index packageByName on Package (name Collate=CI) notunique
```

What's the correct command for creating this index so that it is case insensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to create an index with case insensitive (CI) collate is:

```
CREATE INDEX <name> [ON <class-name> (prop-names [COLLATE <collate>])] <type> [<key-type>] [METADATA {JSON Index Metadata Document}]
```

So:

```
CREATE INDEX packageByName on Package (name COLLATE CI) notunique
```